# How to set POJO Data on swagger for ApiModelProperty

Tags: java, swagger, jsonschema2pojo

I have the following ApiModel for my endpoint -

```
public class CreateConfigRequest {
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "hive")
    String entityType;
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "imports")
    String entityNamespace;
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "hotel")
    String entityName;
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "{\"name\": \"hotel\", \"batch\": {\"type\": \"FullScan\"}}")
    JobConfig content;
}
```

Where JobConfig is another pojo class. Code below :

```
@Data
public class JobConfig {
    @NonNull private String name;
    @NonNull private BatchSpec batch;
    private ProfileConfig profile;
    private ValidateConfig validate;
    private ActionConfig action;
}
```

**My swagger looks like -**
[image]

Which is basically the structure of the POJO.

**How it should look like -**

[image]

Basically i am looking to understand how i can set it to a default JSON structure.

Comment: Can you please add the code for `JobConfig`? Thanks!

Comment: Added the code for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include `profile`, `validate` and `action` at all in your JSONs you can simply use `@JsonIgnore` as follows:

```java
@Data
public class JobConfig {
    @NonNull private String name;
    @NonNull private BatchSpec batch;

    @JsonIgnore
    private ProfileConfig profile;

    @JsonIgnore
    private ValidateConfig validate;

    @JsonIgnore
    private ActionConfig action;
}
```

If you simply don't want to list them in Swagger documentation, you can use `@ApiModelProperty` as follows:

```java
@Data
public class JobConfig {
    @NonNull private String name;
    @NonNull private BatchSpec batch;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private ProfileConfig profile;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private ValidateConfig validate;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private ActionConfig action;
}
```

---

Given that you don't want to hide properties but instead show a more realistic example, try the following:

```java
@Data
public class JobConfig {
    @NonNull 
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "hotel")
    private String name;

    @NonNull 
    private BatchSpec batch;

    private ProfileConfig profile;

    private ValidateConfig validate;

    private ActionConfig action;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class BatchSpec {
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "FullScan")
    private String type;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide it completely, Right now it is showing default structure. I want to create an object and show it on swagger.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following you. Then what do you want to not show and when?

Comment: Right now if you see in the image, it shows "String". I want to put a reasonable value there so create a jobConfig object of my choice and then show it on the swaggger.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. `@ApiModelProperty(example = )` should do it, but I would say you need to annotate each property in `JobConfig` and also in `BatchSpec`, `ProfileConfig`, `ValidateConfig` and `ActionConfig` properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If you see I have @ApiModelProperty(example = "{\"name\": \"hotel\", \"batch\": {\"type\": \"FullScan\"}}") but it does not reflect anything. Also this accepts only String, I don't know how to give it a variable here.

Comment: That is not exactly what I suggested. I will updated my answer.

Comment: How stupid of me to miss this. Thanks for your help! Makes a lot lot more sense. :)

Comment: The devil is in the details ;) You are welcome!